# NSOutlineView add and edit the item

Tags: xcode, macos, nsoutlineview

I have a standard OutlineView on the left pane and Tableview on the right page. The problem is ,when I add a new item to the outlineview using a action, what I want to happen is,

1. Add an item to the outlineview
2. Put it in edit mode immediately and give it focus.
3. When the user had finished editing it, then save the new outline view item to the db.

I can add an new item, but could not put it in the edit mode immediately, any idea how to do it?

Thanks in advance.